# ASP.NET MVC 3 UTF-8 Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unicode, utf-8, character

I'm working on an e-commerce project currently prepairing in Turkish language. So far MVC3 was great but recently today we figure on HTML source there's a problem with some special characters like 'ü', 'ğ', 'ö'...

The problem is accouring on the source code only. The site is clearly visible on browser and characters are understable at all but our fear is for SEO.

Can you please help us on finding a way to use characters as is on both HTML source and views.

So far we tryed to change the meta charset attribute to iso-8859-9 and windows-1254 but wont helped at all.

Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use HtmlString instead of string

```
ViewBag.CanonicalLink = new HtmlString("Yeni Üyelik");
```

and then put use it in the header section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
@if (@ViewBag.Canonical != null){<text>
<link rel="canonical" href="@ViewBag.Canonical" />
</text>}
..
</head>
```